# Hiding a Button And Making It Visible Again

Tags: javascript, html

I've been working for a while to make a button hidden and make it visible when an option af a select is selected. I put all of the code in the picture.The one that I couldn't do is in the bottom. Here is my photo of the basic website. I want to make the buttons on the bottom of the picture hidden when nothing written on the first 2 selects. When the one at the left is Sports and the right one is Tennis, I want to make buttons visible again. Thank you...
[image]

```html
<h3 style="margin-top: 30px;">What Do You Like The Most?</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <select class="form-control" name="hobi" id="hobi" onchange="populate(this.id,'hobi2')" onChange="degistir()" >
            <option value="Not Selected">Not Selected</option>
            <option value="Sports">Sports</option>
            <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
            <option value="Music">Music</option>
            <option value="Art">Art</option>
            <option value="Romantic">Romantic</option>
            <option value="Other">Other</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <select class="form-control" name="hobi2" onChange="hediyeler()" id="hobi2" ></select>
        </div>
      </div>
 
  <script>
  //Select Değişmesi İçin Olan
    function populate(hobi,hobi2){
      var s1 = document.getElementById("hobi");
      var s2 = document.getElementById("hobi2");
      s2.innerHTML = "Not Selected";

      if (s1.value === "Sports"){
        var optionArray = ["not selected | Not Selected", "tennis | Tennis", "basketball | Basketball", "football | Football", "volleyball | volleyball", "swimming | swimming", "athletics | Athletics", "extreme sports | Extreme Sports", "other | Other", "all | All"];

     }else if (s1.value === "Technology"){
        var optionArray = ["not selected | Not Selected", "electronic equipment | Electronic Equipment", "robotics | Robotics", "programming | Programming", "photoshop | Photoshop", "video edit | Video Edit", "other | Other", "all | All"];

      }else if (s1.value === "Music"){
        var optionArray = ["not selected | Not Selected", "piano | Piano", "guitar | Guitar", "violin family | Violin Family", "wind insturments | Wind Insturments", "percussion insturments | Percussion Insturments", "singing | Singing", "electronic music | Electronic Music", "other | Other", "all | All"];

      }else if (s1.value === "Art"){
        var optionArray = ["not selected | Not Selected", "painting | Painting", "3d design | 3D Design", "design | Design", "other | Other", "all | All"];

      }else if (s1.value === "Romantic"){
        var optionArray = ["not selected | Not Selected", "necklace | Necklace", "ring | Ring", "romantic ideas | Romantic Ideas", "other | Other", "all | All"];

      }else if (s1.value === "Other"){
        var optionArray = ["not selected | Not Selected", "no idea | I have No Idea What To Buy", "not find | I Couldn't Find The Best Gift"];
      }
      for(var option in optionArray){
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");
        newOption.value = pair[0];
        newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
        s2.options.add(newOption);
      }
    }

  </script>
  
  
  
  <h3 style="margin-top: 30px">What Is Your Favorite Color?</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
        <select name="renkler" class="form-control" id="renkler">
          <option>Not Selected</option>
          <option>Blue</option>
          <option>Pink</option>
          <option>Red</option>
          <option>Purple</option>
          <option>Yellow</option>
          <option>White</option>
          <option>Black</option>
          <option>Brown</option>
          <option>Turquoise</option>
          <option>Green</option>
          <option>Gray</option>
          <option>Bisque</option>
          <option>Orange</option>
          <option>All</option>
          <option>I'm Not Sure</option>
          <option>I don't want to say</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      </div>
  
  <div class="first_question">
  <div class="first">
   <a href="#" id="raket"><button>Racket</button></a>
   <a href="#" id="ayakkabi"><button>Shoes</button></a>
   <a href="#" id="diger"><button>Other</button></a>
   </div>
    <div class="second">
   <a href="#" id="baskettop"><button>Basketball</button></a>
   <a href="#" id="basketkabi"><button>Basketball Shoes</button></a>
   </div>
  </div>
  
  
    
    
    //Here is my Javascript code that I couldn't make it work. I put the others for you to understand what am I doing well.
    <script>
   var secme1 = document.getElementById("hobi");
   var secme2 = document.getElementById("hobi2");
   var st1 = document.getElementById("raket");
   var st2 = document.getElementById("ayakkabi");
   var st3 = document.getElementById("diger");
   var sb1 = document.getElementById("baskettop");
   var sb2 = document.getElementById("basketkabi");
   if (function degistir(){
    st1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    st2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    st3.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    sb1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    sb2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    
    if (function hediyeler(){
       if (secme1 === "Sports" && secme2 === "Tennis"){
       st1.style.visibility = 'visible';
    st2.style.visibility = 'visible';
    st3.style.visibility = 'visible';

       }
   });
    });else{
    st1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    st2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    st3.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    sb1.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    sb2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

  
  </script>
```

Comment: You can give your div containing buttons an Id and based on your logic you can say something like
document.getElementById("buttonDiv").style.display = "none" //for hiding;
document.getElementById("buttonDiv").style.display = "block"; //for displaying

Comment: just make one thing clear here, you want to show the options selected by the user as buttons below. am I getting it right?

Comment: Actually I want to show a different button if you select an option. For example if you select Sports option and Tennis option, it will show buttons but if you don't select anything it will hide them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Although your requirements are not clear in your question, here is a solution on the bases of what I understood by your question, I have just made this snippet for first three options, check if this works for you, if no then tell me the exact changes, is ill try to help you out.
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var selectedOptionforHobi1;
    $("select#hobi").change(function() {
        selectedOptionforHobi1 = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        if (selectedOptionforHobi1 != 'NA') {
            $("select#hobi2").html("");
            $("#hobi2").show();
            if (selectedOptionforHobi1 == "sports") {
                $("select#hobi2").html("<option value='NA' selected>Not Selected</option><option value='Tennis'>Tennis</option><option value='Basketball'>Basketball</option><option value='Football'>Football</option><option value='Other'>Other</option><option value='All'>All</option>");
            } else if (selectedOptionforHobi1 == "tech") {
                $("select#hobi2").html("<option value='NA' selected>Not Selected</option><option value='Electronic Equipment'>Electronic Equipment</option><option value='Robotics'>Robotics</option><option value='Programming'>Programming</option><option value='Photoshop'>Photoshop</option><option value='all'>all</option>");
            } else if (selectedOptionforHobi1 == "music") {
                $("select#hobi2").html("<option value='NA' selected>Not Selected</option><option value='Piano'>Piano</option><option value='Guitar'>Guitar</option><option value='Violin Family'>Violin Family</option><option value='Electronic Music'>Electronic Music</option><option value='Other'>Other</option>");
            }
        }
        return selectedOptionforHobi1;
    });
    $(document).on('change', '#hobi2', function() {
        var selectedOption = $(this).children("option:selected").val();
        if (selectedOption == 'Tennis' && selectedOptionforHobi1 == 'sports') {
            $(".first_question>div").hide();
            $(".first_question .first").show();

        }
        if (selectedOption == 'Basketball' && selectedOptionforHobi1 == 'sports') {
            $(".first_question>div").hide();
            $(".first_question .second").show();

        }
    });
});
```

```css
.first_question>div {
        display: none;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3 style="margin-top: 30px;">What Do You Like The Most?</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <select class="form-control" name="hobi" id="hobi">
                <option value="NA" selected>Not Selected</option>
                <option value="sports">Sports</option>
                <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                <option value="music">Music</option>
                <option value="art">Art</option>
                <option value="romantic">Romantic</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control" name="hobi2" id="hobi2">
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h3 style="margin-top: 30px">What Is Your Favorite Color?</h3>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <select name="renkler" class="form-control" id="renkler">
                <option>Not Selected</option>
                <option>Blue</option>
                <option>Pink</option>
                <option>Red</option>
                <option>Purple</option>
                <option>Yellow</option>
                <option>White</option>
                <option>Black</option>
                <option>Brown</option>
                <option>Turquoise</option>
                <option>Green</option>
                <option>Gray</option>
                <option>Bisque</option>
                <option>Orange</option>
                <option>All</option>
                <option>I'm Not Sure</option>
                <option>I don't want to say</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="first_question">
        <div class="first">
            <button>Butotns in first div</button>
            <button>Butotns in first div</button>
            <button>Butotns in first div</button>
            <button>Butotns in first div</button>
        </div>
        <div class="second">
            <button>Butotns in second div</button>
            <button>Butotns in second div</button>
            <button>Butotns in second div</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This was great but not like I wanted. Sorry if I couldn't explain well. I only want to make some buttons visible when an option on hobi2 is selected. I don't want to write the options the users select on buttons. For example if I select "Sports" for hobi and "Tennis" for hobi 2, I will see the buttons on <div class = "first">. When I select basketball for hobi2, I will see the buttons on <div class = "second>. When I don't select these options, it will stay hidden.

Comment: That's easy @CanKURC, modifying the code for you, but in this case, your code will not be dynamic, you have to write custom functionality for each option, doing it for start 2 options as you asked. check in a while

Comment: above code changed as per your requirements you mentioned in the comment above, if need something else as well, feel free to ask

Comment: That was what I wanted. Thank you so much.